# Imputing missing data conditional on other values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, lm, tidymodels

I working on a longitudinal patient dataset with some missing data. I'm trying to replicate a missing data imputation approach used by a published study. A snapshot of the first 18 rows of this dataset is below. Briefly, here there are 6 patients belonging to 3 different groups. Each person has been assessed over 3 years across a variety of tests. There is also information on Age, disease severity and a functional capacity score:

```
ID Group Time Age Severity Func.score Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
  1     A    1  60        5         50    -4   888     5     4
  1     A    2  61        6         45     3     3     4     4
  1     A    3  62        7         40     2     2   888     4
  2     A    1  59        5         50     5     3     6     3
  2     A    2  60        6         40     4     2     5     3
  2     A    3  61        7         35     3     1   888     2
  3     B    1  59        6         40    -4    -4     7     5
  3     B    2  59        7         40     3     3     7     5
  3     B    3  60        8         30     1   888   888     2
  4     B    1  55        7         50     5   888     7     4
  4     B    2  56        8         NA     3     1     6     3
  4     B    3  57        9         NA     1    -4     6   888
  5     C    1  54        7         40     6     6     5     5
  5     C    2  55        8         40     4     5     5     4
  5     C    3  56        8         35     2   888     5     3
  6     C    1  60        6         50     6     7     4     4
  6     C    2  61        6         40     5     6     4   888
  6     C    3  62        7         30     3     5     4   888
```

Missing data in this dataset is coded in 3 possible ways. If `NA`, then the measure was not administered. If `-4`, the person could not complete the test due to a cognitive problem (i.e., they have poor memory etc.). If `888`, then the person couldn't complete the test because of a physical problem (i.e., they have difficulty writing, drawing etc.).

My aim is to impute this missing data using two strategies.

1. If the missing data are because of a cognitive problem (i.e., where -4), then I want to impute the lowest possible score, given their specific time point and group membership. For example, for Test1 for ID1, I want the -4 substituted with 5 (as that is the only score that belongs to Time 1 and Group A).
2. If the missing data are because of a physical problem (i.e., where 888), I want to impute this using a regression equation using Age, Severity, and Functional score (Func.score) and all other available Test scores to predict that missing data point.

How can I build this conditional imputing into a `dplyr::mutate` or an `ifelse` or `case_when` function?

Comment: I would think the first step is to create a helper table for what the replacement should be - make a table with a row for each combination of `ID` and `Group` and use a formula to calculate the minimum value for each test, ignoring -4 and 888 values.  you can then use  `mutate()` and `replace()` to substitute the -4 values in the main dataset.

Answer (score -1):

In tidymodels, you would have to set them to `NA` and not use coded values (I really do wish that we had different types of missing values).

No guarantees on this since we don't have a reproducible example but this might work for you:

```r
some_recipe %>% 
  # for case 1 in your post
  step_mutate(Test1 = ifelse(Test1 == -4, 5, Test1)) %>% 
  # for case 2
  step_mutate(
    # probably better to do this with across()
    Test1 = ifelse(Test1 == 888, NA_integer_, Test1),
    Test2 = ifelse(Test2 == 888, NA_integer_, Test2),
    Test3 = ifelse(Test3 == 888, NA_integer_, Test3),
    Test4 = ifelse(Test4 == 888, NA_integer_, Test4)
    ) %>%  
  step_impute_linear(starts_with("Test"), 
                     impute_with = vars(Age, Severity, Func.score, 
                                        starts_with("Test")))
```